# How far can you get in an ultra before you go from jogging to running?

Tags: running, nutrition, long-distance-running

Jogging is running without effort or worrying about how fast you go. Running requires pushing slightly at the least while worrying about time. This question is for all the marathoners who transitioned to Ultras for the challenge. If training experience is needed lets say 50-100 miles/week and marathon capability is about 3 hours even. Thanks.

Comment: By "how far" do you mean mileage or generalized progress? It seems a little obvious that if you never run in an ultra you'll never be competing with those who do, and as such you'll never get really competitive.

Comment: @EricKaufman I mean mileage. In a single ultra. Thanks

Comment: Jog...for who? Run...for who? Everybody is different, this is very highly individualized and personal opinion.

Comment: @JohnP For anyone. Looking for first or second hand experience. Oh, I said who and defined jogging in the question :)

Comment: @Jason - There have been many races that felt without effort that were very fast for me. A lot of all of this is personal and subjective, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The amount of milage your run every week is dependant on your age, fitness level, trail vs road, goals and finally the definition of "Run vs Jog". The hard part is that as humans we are all different and our bodies all react differently to training. Some people can run 60k or less and successfully "Run" an ultra.

The other variable is how many races you have done and what distances. For example if you have only trained for a Marathon and you have completed the Marathon in 3 hours  it stand to reason that you could RUN a 50k in 3:38 (Using this calculator https://www.mcmillanrunning.com)

If you are already running a 3 hour marathon then you already know the effort it takes to get to that level.

Finally, almost all 50k races are done on the trail. You should expect a much slower pace on trails as well as much different elevation changes. You can't really judge a pace on your trail races compared to a road race.

Answer (score 0):

Id say up to 50k the first half is a jog, second half is a run and last quarter is hard running. This matches my favorite race strategy that tends to work so this is most likely biased.

Its interestimg to see what happens for a run of +6 hours when the half way mark is much longer than a normal long training run.